# RoutePluginManager exception when running index.php from command line

Tags: zend-framework2

I was trying to integrate Console module on my ZF2 project which currently has 2 other working modules. I have created an Application module and started to configure the routing like it's described in http://framework.zend.com/manual/2.1/en/modules/zend.console.introduction.html

but if I run `php index.php` from command line (with or without routing parameters) I get this long and strange exception:

```
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught exception 'Zend\ServiceManager\Exception\ServiceNotFoundException' with message 'Zend\Mvc\Router\RoutePluginManager::get was unable to fetch or create an instance for Segment' in /www/APIO/vendor/zendframework/zendframework/library/Zend/ServiceManager/ServiceManager.php:496
Stack trace:
#0 /www/APIO/vendor/zendframework/zendframework/library/Zend/ServiceManager/AbstractPluginManager.php(103): Zend\ServiceManager\ServiceManager->get('Segment', true)
#1 /www/APIO/vendor/zendframework/zendframework/library/Zend/Mvc/Router/SimpleRouteStack.php(274): Zend\ServiceManager\AbstractPluginManager->get('Segment', Array)
#2 /www/APIO/vendor/zendframework/zendframework/library/Zend/Mvc/Router/Console/SimpleRouteStack.php(78): Zend\Mvc\Router\SimpleRouteStack->routeFromArray(Array)
#3 /www/APIO/vendor/zendframework/zendframework/library/Zend/Mvc/Router/Console/SimpleRouteStack.php(51): Zend\Mvc\Router\Console\SimpleRouteStack->routeFromArray(Array)
#4 /www/APIO/vendor/zendframework/zendframework/library/Zend/Mvc/R in /www/APIO/vendor/zendframework/zendframework/library/Zend/ServiceManager/ServiceManager.php on line 496

Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Zend\ServiceManager\Exception\ServiceNotFoundException' with message 'Zend\Mvc\Router\RoutePluginManager::get was unable to fetch or create an instance for Segment' in /www/APIO/vendor/zendframework/zendframework/library/Zend/ServiceManager/ServiceManager.php on line 496

Zend\ServiceManager\Exception\ServiceNotFoundException: Zend\Mvc\Router\RoutePluginManager::get was unable to fetch or create an instance for Segment in /www/APIO/vendor/zendframework/zendframework/library/Zend/ServiceManager/ServiceManager.php on line 496

Call Stack:
    0.0011     636880   1. {main}() /www/APIO/public/index.php:0
    0.0048     933624   2. Zend\Mvc\Application::init() /www/APIO/public/index.php:21
    0.0752    6943968   3. Zend\Mvc\Application->bootstrap() /www/APIO/vendor/zendframework/zendframework/library/Zend/Mvc/Application.php:254
    0.0815    7543504   4. Zend\ServiceManager\ServiceManager->get() /www/APIO/vendor/zendframework/zendframework/library/Zend/Mvc/Application.php:153
    0.0815    7544296   5. Zend\ServiceManager\ServiceManager->create() /www/APIO/vendor/zendframework/zendframework/library/Zend/ServiceManager/ServiceManager.php:481
    0.0815    7544296   6. Zend\ServiceManager\ServiceManager->doCreate() /www/APIO/vendor/zendframework/zendframework/library/Zend/ServiceManager/ServiceManager.php:557
    0.0816    7544376   7. Zend\ServiceManager\ServiceManager->createFromFactory() /www/APIO/vendor/zendframework/zendframework/library/Zend/ServiceManager/ServiceManager.php:598
    0.0819    7565176   8. Zend\ServiceManager\ServiceManager->createServiceViaCallback() /www/APIO/vendor/zendframework/zendframework/library/Zend/ServiceManager/ServiceManager.php:983
```

I've tried to google for this exception, but had no luck. Does anyone know what's this 'Segment' service that could not be created? Or maybe something is misconfigured in my application?

PS. Following some other tutorials, my Module.php looks like this:

```
class Module implements AutoloaderProviderInterface,
    ConfigProviderInterface,
    ConsoleUsageProviderInterface
{


    public function getConfig()
    {
        return include __DIR__ . '/config/module.config.php';
    }

    public function getAutoloaderConfig()
    {
        return array(
            'Zend\Loader\StandardAutoloader' => array(
                'namespaces' => array(
                    __NAMESPACE__ => __DIR__ . '/src/' . __NAMESPACE__,
                ),
            ),
        );
    }

    /**
     * Returns a string containing a banner text, that describes the module and/or the application.
     * The banner is shown in the console window, when the user supplies invalid command-line parameters or invokes
     * the application with no parameters.
     *
     * The method is called with active Zend\Console\Adapter\AdapterInterface that can be used to directly access Console and send
     * output.
     *
     * @param Console $console
     * @return string|null
     */
    public function getConsoleBanner(Console $console)
    {
        // TODO: Implement getConsoleBanner() method.
        return 'Application 1.0';
    }

    public function getConsoleUsage(Console $console)
    {
        return array(
            'show stats'             => 'Show application statistics',
            'run cron'               => 'Run automated jobs',
            '(enable|disable) debug' => 'Enable or disable debug mode for the application.'
        );
    }
}
```

**EDIT**

Also here is the module.config.php file

```
<?php

return array(
    'router' => array(
        'routes' => array(
        ),
        'console' => array(
            'calculate-distances' => array(
                'options' => array(
                    'route'    => 'user calculatedistances [--id=]',
                    'defaults' => array(
                        'controller' => 'Application\Controller\Index',
                        'action'     => 'calculate-distances'
                    )
                )
            )
        )
    ),

    'controllers' => array(
        'invokables' => array(
            'Application\Controller\Index' => 'Application\Controller\IndexController'
        ),
    ),
    'service_manager' => array(
        'abstract_factories' => array(
            'Zend\Cache\Service\StorageCacheAbstractServiceFactory',
            'Zend\Log\LoggerAbstractServiceFactory',
        ),
    ),
);
```

Comment: Can you add your module.config.php file? I'm guessing you have some segment routes defined in your console router, which I don't think are valid.

Comment: just added. see the edits

Comment: @aydin-hassan, as I know, if you don't specify the type it's considered "simple" in console routes. But even adding it as `'type' => 'simple'` did not help.

Comment: Youre config is wrong. `console` key should be a top level key. Not inside `router` :) You you should have 'console' => 'router' => 'routes'